# The gen.key file at /etc/mongodb-mms/gen.key does not match the gen.key already used

Tags: mongodb

I am using docker to deploy mongodb ops manager, then i get the following error message

`The gen.key file at /etc/mongodb-mms/gen.key does not match the gen.key already used for this Ops Manager installation. The key file for this Ops Manager server must be copied from another server.`

I only deployed ops in a node, where should I copy this file from it?

Answer (score 3):

First, make sure that your key is at `/etc/mongodb-mms/gen.key` and the permissions are correct so that the owner of the `mongodb-mms` service can read the key.

If you have tried to start the `mongodb-mms` service already, you may need to drop the configuration databases and try again.

To do this, connect to your replica set (or single mongod in your case) with the shell, `show dbs` and and drop every database that isn't `admin` or `local`. For example:

`use mmsdbconfig`

`db.dropDatabase()`

Try to start ops manager again:

`sudo service mongodb-mms start`

Comment: This is working!

As ops manager creates multiple database, they can be dropped using script:

var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in dbs){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( dbs[i] );
    if (db.getName() !== 'admin' && db.getName() !== 'local') 
    {
        print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );  
        db.dropDatabase();
    }
}

Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51521199/how-to-drop-all-databases-in-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

I had recently same  problem . In my case ops-manager and mongodb are running on Docker container. "The gen.key file at /etc/mongodb-mms/gen.key does not match the gen.key already used " problem is , if you would like to run ops-manager on your server as a service , ops-manager uses gen.key file once it was generated at first time. But if ops-manager is running on docker container , when every running the container, it creates a new gen.key file inside container, that’s why gen.key file doesn’t match previous one. You can test it so. Actually i solved this problem , i extract the gen.key file from docker container after i run container. Then i restarted container then i looked the logs and i saw  this error again "The gen.key file at /etc/mongodb-mms/gen.key does not match the gen.key already used ".. Then i copied gen.key file which i extracted , into docker container , then it started to work.