# How to drop all databases in MongoDB?

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I have a list of databases in my MongoDB. How to delete all databases except `local`, `admin`, and `config`?
[image]

Comment: Interesting. There appears to be no method to enumerate databases (or their names) in a code-friendly way. There is one for collections, but not databases.

Comment: if you know the name, it's trivial: `db.getSiblingDB('Marks').dropDatabase()`. So you could simply hardcode these names.

Comment: Check it [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3366397/delete-everything-in-a-mongodb-database]

Comment: @SergioTulentsev actually there is a method to do that, it's just not formally documented. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `getDBNames()` method in the `mongo` shell.

This method must be called from the [`Mongo()` instance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Mongo/#Mongo). Unfortunately I don't think the `getDBNames()` method is documented.

After getting the database names, you can then loop through them to drop the unwanted ones using something like:

```
Mongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(x) {
  // loop through all the database names
  if (['admin', 'config', 'local'].indexOf(x) < 0) {
    // drop database if it's not admin, config, or local
    Mongo().getDB(x).dropDatabase();
  }
})
```

For example:

```
> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.001GB
test    0.000GB
test2   0.000GB
test3   0.000GB

> Mongo().getDBNames().forEach(function(x) {
...   if (['admin', 'config', 'local'].indexOf(x) < 0) {
...     Mongo().getDB(x).dropDatabase();
...   }
... })

> show dbs
admin   0.000GB
config  0.000GB
local   0.001GB
```

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue using solution from this [tutorial](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2017/06/24/delete-all-mongo-db-except-admin-and-local/)

I ran this code in my mongo shell:

```
var dbs = db.getMongo().getDBNames()
for(var i in dbs){
    db = db.getMongo().getDB( dbs[i] );
    if (db.getName() !== 'admin' && db.getName() !== 'local') 
    {
        print( "dropping db " + db.getName() );  
        db.dropDatabase();
    }
}
```